# Cannot read the query in sqlite when run a function

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am writing a piece of code that can filter the date and month from the database, but the query still cannot be read, please help me.

```
def Filter(self):
    print("filter is called")
    sortDay = ""
    sortMonth = ""
    #sortYear = ""
    sortDay = self.sortDay.text()
    sortMonth = self.sortMonth.text()
    #sortYear = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        query = ("SELECT id,staff_name,working_day,Satisfaction,Satisfaction_level"
                 " FROM db_ViewStatitis"
                 " WHERE strftime('%d',working_day) IN('{}') AND strftime('%m',working_day) IN('{}')".format(str(sortDay+ sortMonth)))
        print(query)
        c = connection.cursor()
        result = c.execute(query)
        print(c.fetchone())
        row = result.fetchone()
        print(query)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        connection.close()
    except Exception:
        QMessageBox.warning(QMessageBox(), 'Error', 'Could not Find employee from the database.')
```

Comment: In `query = ...` you have two placeholders for `format`, Where are the two values that should replace them?

Comment: you might try setting `connection.row_factory = sq3Row` and `connection.text_factory = str` --- I use both of those as standard elements in all my connections the first uses the native structure that mostly resembles a Recordset/Dictionary and the second one removes the unicode prefix from a string -- also I do a `result.fetchall()` and then simply handle all the data coming back from the database in one chunk but most of my query results for unless your data mining if you have created you database properly then the amount of data will not be unhandable by the program

Comment: This makes your access to the database more streamlined -- open connection, execute SQL, retrieve all data, close connection -- now something else can have access to that database -- not a big deal when you have solo access but multiple access to the same database it shines big time -- and it does not hurt you solo access to do this as well -- aka just a general all around good practice